# What's the best way to organize personal configurations in Spacemacs?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, configuration-files

For plain Emacs, I used to use the following methods to organize my configurations:

1. Put logically related configurations into different files;
2. Organize with Org Babel.

Now I'm trying to use Spacemace, it seems that all user configurations goes into `dotspacemacs/user-init` and `dotspacemacs/user-config`.  If all my configs are put inside these two procedures, it will be a big chunk of code.  Is there a way to separate the configs neatly?

For example, I have quite some Org mode configurations.  There's already a layer for Org mode in Spacemacs.  Then my personal configs should go somewhere else.  What's the best way to deal with that?

Comment: Define *best way*. Seems primarily opinion-based. Can you pose a more specific question?

Comment: How have you been loading your configurations from the separate files? And is there any reason you can't load them from within `dotspacemacs/user-config`?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that to manage configurations you should create one or more layer(s). Click [here](http://spacemacs.org/doc/LAYERS.html#orgheadline1) for documentation.